# flex-wrap property not working on mobile screen

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I need help if anyone can help . I am having flex-wrap property not working on mobile screens but it works fine when i shrink my browser width. Toggling device toolbar doesn't allows wrap property to work. I need this for my upcoming project and its important. Please help me (see attached screenshots url i have uploaded)

https://ibb.co/e1nBbo
https://ibb.co/mSYjwo

and here is my code :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item1">First Box</div>
  <div class="item2">Second Box</div>
  <div class="item3">Third Box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use a media query to make them 100% width and force the wrap?

Comment: I can't figure out whats wrong, you just have to select `Responsive` as device and play with the widths...

Comment: your problem is interesting but I regret that your image and the comment in image are not put directly in your question !

Comment: Your question is not enough explicit. When I read it for the first time I think that you have an issue ON Mobile device, but in reality, I think that you have a problem on a development tools used on a specific browser. If my supposition is exact, can you modify your question to precise which browser you use ?

Comment: Hello schlebe , thanks for viewing and taking time to answer my question. Yes it was actually on mobile and we can see the different mobile views through the browser developer tool. I got it sorted as i have received and answer that worked. 
I was missing this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> on my Html <head>

Comment: @schogges and pete . Thankyou for taking time to answer actually i tried many ways and ended up with the solution that i was missing this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` on your Html `<head>`.